# attempted import error from downloaded dependency

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

In my downloaded package module @react-three, it's giving me an attempted import error.

> ./node_modules/@react-three/drei/node_modules/troika-three-text/dist/troika-three-text.esm.js
> Attempted import error: 'webgl-sdf-generator' does not contain a default export (imported as 'createSDFGenerator').

i tried to follow the path and tamper the file in the node module.
went to the `C:\Users\babid\Documents\Web Development\personal-site\node_modules\webgl-sdf-generator\dist\webgl-sdf-generator.js` where the 'createSDFGenerator' is being exported.

tried to put `export default createSDFGenerator` in the `C:\Users\babid\Documents\Web Development\personal-site\node_modules\webgl-sdf-generator\dist\webgl-sdf-generator.js`

i saw a solution where i should put a bracket around 'createSDFGenerator' in the `C:\Users\babid\Documents\Web Development\personal-site\node_modules\webgl-sdf-generator\dist\webgl-sdf-generator.js` but it's still giving me an error.

the whole log:

```
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@react-three/drei/node_modules/troika-three-text/dist/troika-three- 
text.esm.js
./node_modules/@react-three/drei/core/Text.js
./node_modules/@react-three/drei/index.js
./app/aboutMe/canvas/Ball.jsx
./app/aboutMe/Tech.tsx
 ⚠ ./node_modules/@react-three/drei/node_modules/troika-three-text/dist/troika-three- 
   text.esm.js
Attempted import error: 'webgl-sdf-generator' does not contain a default export (imported as 'createSDFGenerator').
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, searching online and got information that it is due to nextjs, which I suppose you must be using it

I wanted a prototype urgently I shifted to vite